# Delete sessions generated by search engine spiders

Tags: asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP web application that is storing user session info to a database table. This particular site is constantly getting hit by search engine spiders and other bots, I believe mostly due to its domain name. I am storing the IP address of each user, and many of them I can trace back to Russian and Ukrainian sources, which is probably bad news.

Anyway, I want to keep my table from getting filled up with records that are not actual users. Because the bots do not accept cookies, the application doesn't realize its the same "user" over and over again, and keeps writing new records.

I don't know that I can identify these bots on-the-fly and simply not write a record to the table. As far as I know, all the ASP cookie tests involve multiple files, so I probably can't do this in the context of my session script.

My next thought was to simply delete records from the table when the same IP address appears X number of times. I know some internet providers share IP addresses. But if I were to say something like:

delete from table where (number of duplicate IP addresses)>100

Would that be reasonably safe? To assume that there would never be 100 users from the same IP address maintaining sessions on this website?

I am open to any suggestions on other ways to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you setup a `robots.txt` or at the very least have `noindex,nofollow` on your login page? If these bots are violating that, then I would consider creating a blacklist of ip addresses or checking the `useragent` string (but this can be spoofed). Either way you detect them you either want to `Response.End` to kill the connection or `Response.Status = "404 Not Found"` so the bot knows not to try again.

Answer (score 3):

Well, every browser sends a unique user agent string and so is every bot or spider.

You can check that string against array of common key words to get an almost sure identification:

```vbs
Function IsBotOrSpider()
    Dim arrBots, strUserAgent, x
    IsBotOrSpider = False
    arrBots = Array("bot", "spider", "crawler", "indexer", "archiver", "slurp", "http://")
    strUserAgent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
    For x=0 To UBound(arrBots)
        If InStr(LCase(strUserAgent), LCase(arrBots(x)))>0 Then
            IsBotOrSpider = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Having this function you can check for bot/spider in every request, and if true don't store the session:

```vbs
If IsBotOrSpider() Then
    'do not store session, this is not a human visitor
Else  
    'human visitor ahead, deal properly
End If
```

If you want to be almost 100% safe, you can get list of bots agent strings [here](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/bots).

Comment: Your assuming the bot decides to follow the rules they can set the user-agent string to anything they like even spoof a browser user-agent string.

Comment: It's just the *"almost sure identification"* I was referring to, I don't think you can solely rely on the user-agent string.

Comment: @Lankymart true, but it's impossible to detect those, unless you put Captcha in every page load which is of course insane. My assumption is that most legit bots/crawlers will send proper user agent string, and those are the spiders the OP here want to detect. :)

Comment: For now, I am using this solution, thank you it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you create a `cookie` before create a `session`. Well, if the BOT can't store this cookie, why you don't test the cookie before create the session?

Only create the session if the cookie exists:

```
<% if len(Request.Cookies("cookieName"))>0 then %>
```

This is my first Idea. I will think a little bit more and edit this if I find something better.

Comment: Because if a real user is hitting the website for the first time, they also would not have a cookie stored.

Comment: You should create the cookie before that. If the user is a robot like you said, this cookie will not be created, so after create the cookie, test it and create the session if the cookie exist. Don't matter if the user access your website for the first time.

Comment: @BBDesign I get MarceloBarbosa point and it's not a bad one. You could give every visitor a one off cookie then check for the existence of that cookie as a way of sniffing out the bots. That will confirm whether they support cookies or not then deal with them accordingly. +1

Comment: I am doing this with Classic ASP. If I set a cookie at the beginning of a script, then check for it later in the script, the cookie will show as valid… even if the browser does not accept cookies. Its only when you pass the value from one page to another that this technique would work, at least under Classic ASP.